# What is recommended to fill openings between panels

Tags: hardwood-floor

I believe wood paneling was used on my mudroom floor. Dirt collects in the crevices. Is there a way to level the floor,by filling in the cervices.

Comment: can you add a photo please?

Comment: Some house renovators I know installed "seconds" 3/4" thick hardwood plank flooring in a house they are renovating. The seconds have gaps which they filled with a product described to me as wood glue with sawdust. It is troweled on and forced into the gaps. Then the floor is sanded with a belt floor sander. Perhaps this product would work to fill the gaps in your panels.